# How to generate all the delete commands for all the tables of a database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate all the commands to empty all the tables in my database. Right now I'm using DBeaver and my database is PostgreSQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    table_name TEXT;
    delete_commands TEXT := '';
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'xxx'
          AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        delete_commands := delete_commands || 'DELETE FROM xxx.' || quote_ident(table_rec.table_name) || ';' || E'\n';
    END LOOP;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'Lista de comandos DELETE generada: %', delete_commands;
END $$;
```

I'm having problems with the request. Does someone know how to fix it?

My actual error is:

> SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated dollar quote started at position 4 in SQL END $$;. Expected terminating $$

Comment: Can you try with `DO $$DECLARE` without the whitespaces? See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad , when I try what U propose, I get the following error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables
  Position: 85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your goal is to clear data from the schema. Rather than `delete` from each table you may want to use `truncate` instead (if you have sufficient authorization). It will be much faster. Further if all tables with FKs are mentioned then it would not be subject to getting the order exactly correct. Additionally, if desired you can reset any autogenerated sequence value. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html) and the [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/un9ZecRI)

```
-- truncate parent, xchild, ychild restart identity;
do $$
begin 
    execute (select 'truncate ' || string_agg(table_schema || '.' || table_name, ',') || ' restart identity;'
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'public'
          AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE' );
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for this:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG('', FORMAT('DELETE FROM %I.%I;', table_schema, table_name))
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'xxx'
  AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

The function [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) takes care of the double quotes, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
do $$DECLARE
    table_rec RECORD;
    delete_commands TEXT := '';
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'xxx'
          AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        delete_commands := delete_commands || 'DELETE FROM xxx.' || quote_ident(table_rec.table_name) || ';' || E'\n';
    END LOOP;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'Lista de comandos DELETE generada: %', delete_commands;
END $$;
```